# Finding the Maclaurin series representation

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$$f(x)=\frac { x }{ { (2-x) }^{ 2 } }$$

I tried finding the first derivative, the second derivative, and so on, but it just keeps getting more complicated, so I suspect I have to use binomial series.

The issue is that binomial series needs to have the form of ${ (1+x) }^{ k }$ but I can't get it into that form. Any idea to get f(x) into that form? The x outside won't go inside the brackets.

Here is the theorem: http://s9.postimg.org/u4qwkrmv3/Binomial_Series.png

Also, my textbook has only one example on binomial series and it is a simpler example.

Attempt:

$$f(x)=\frac { x }{ { (2-x) }^{ 2 } } \\ f(x)=\frac { x }{ 4{ (1-\frac { x }{ 2 } ) }^{ 2 } } \\ f(x)=\frac { 1 }{ 4{ x }^{ -1 }{ (1-\frac { x }{ 2 } ) }^{ 2 } }$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

$$\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{x}{4} \left (1-\frac{x}{2} \right )^{-2}\\ &= \frac{x}{4} \left [1 - 2 \left ( \frac{x}{2}\right ) + \frac{(-2)(-3)}{2!}\left ( \frac{x}{2}\right )^2 + \ldots  \right ]\\ &= \frac{x}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (k+1) \left ( \frac{x}{2}\right )^k \end{align}$$

Comment: But you've left x outside the brackets?

Comment: Oh... I see. I get it now. I guess you can put x/4 back into the infinite sum with some algebra.

Comment: @user72708: Yes, that's right.  It's really not very much, I figure you can handle it.

Comment: http://s12.postimg.org/mavzwawml/IMG_20130415_135519.jpg What did I do wrong here to get x/0 at the end? Sorry for poor quality.

Comment: $-n-1=-(n+1)$, not $-(n-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ and taking derivatives 
$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)z^n$

so $\frac{z}{(2-z)^2}=\frac{z}{4(1-z/2)^2}=\frac{z}{4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2^n}z^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}z^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $2-x=2\left(1-\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

So basically we want $\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$. We can use the generalized binomial theorem, or else, more simply, calculate the coefficient of $t^k$ in
$$(1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots)(1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots).$$
If you imagine multiplying out, you will see that the coefficients are quite simple.

An alternate approach is to note that $\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$ is the **derivative** of $\frac{1}{1-t}$.

You can use that sort of observation directly with $\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$. But then you still need the expansion of $\frac{1}{2-x}$. For that, use the hint.

Comment: I've posted my attempt. Still not sure how to put x in the brackets.