# Can someone claify on the work that was done in this question on Maclaurin Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question was here: [Finding the Maclaurin series representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362567/finding-the-maclaurin-series-representation?rq=1)

One user posted:

$$\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{x}{4} \left (1-\frac{x}{2} \right )^{-2}\\ &= \frac{x}{4} \left [1 - 2 \left ( \frac{x}{2}\right ) + \frac{(-2)(-3)}{2!}\left ( \frac{x}{2}\right )^2 + \ldots  \right ]\\ &= \frac{x}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (k+1) \left ( \frac{x}{2}\right )^k \end{align}$$

I understand how he got to the first line: $f(x) = \frac{x}{4} \left (1-\frac{x}{2} \right )^{-2}\\ $

However I don't understand how he got from the first line to the second line and then to the conclusion.

Comment: Many ways. General binomial theorem. Or look at the familiar series for $\frac{1}{1-t}$ and differentiate term by term.

Answer (score 0):

The second line is a binomal expansion

$(1 + a)^n =  1 + n a + \frac {n(n-1)}{2!} a^2 + \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} a^3 \cdots $

$a = \frac x2, n = -2$

When $n = -2, \dfrac {(n)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{k!}=(-1)^k(k+1)$

and $3^{rd}$ line follows fairly naturally in the simplification.

Alternative:

$g(x) = \frac 1{2-x} = \frac 12\sum_\limits {n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (\frac x2)^n\\
f(x) = -\frac x4 g'(x)  = -\frac x8\sum (-1)^n (\frac n2) (\frac x2)^{n-1}\\
\sum (-1)^{n+1} \frac {n x^n}{2^{n+3}}$